# Lambda left join with rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have two tables. A table called `Order` and a table called `OrderRows`.

An `Order` can have zero or more `OrderRows`.

I want to query all Orders and do a `Sum` for all OrderRows that belong to that `Order`.

I do that like this:

```
var model = await _dbContext.Orders
    .Join(_dbContext.OrderRows, o => o.Id, or => or.OrderId, (o, or) => new {o, or})
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.o.Id,
        x.o.Name
    })
    .Select(g => new CustomDto
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        TotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.wkr.Price)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

This works fine for all Orders that have OrderRows. However, some Orders don't have any OrderRows (yet).

Right now the Orders that don't have any OrderRows, are not included in  the result.

In those cases I still want to have them in my result, but with a `TotalPrice` of `0`.

What do I have to change in my Lambda query?

Comment: You need left join. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21584913/809357

Comment: First I'd suggest using navigation properties.  I assume `Orders` has a `OrderRows` property you can use instead of joining.

Comment: Indeed- it's the *ORM*'s job to create JOINs from the navigation properties. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL and domain entities aren't tables.

Comment: With proper navigation properties you could write `from order in Orders
from row in order.Rows
group row by order into g
select new {g.Key.Id, g.Key.Name,Sum=g.Sum(x=>x.wkr.Price)}`

Comment: Writing the same thing using methods `Orders.SelectMany(order=>order.Rows).GroupBy(row=>row.Order).Select(g=>new {g.Key.Id,g.Key.Name,Sum=g.Sum(x=>x.wkr.Price)});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `Select` without grouping. Just calculate `TotalPrice` as sub-query:

```
var model = await _dbContext.Orders.Select(o => new CustomDto
    {
      Id = o.Id,
      Name = o.Name,
      TotalPrice = _dbContext.OrderRows.Where(or => or.OrderId == o.Id).Sum(or => or.wkr.Price)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

I've not tested it, but hope that idea is clear